# Typescript compiler transpile the code into which version of Javascript by default?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-typescript

I am new to Typescript and in the introductory lessons I got to know that Typescript compiler compiles your typescript code into vanilla Javascript. It also has the capability to convert your code into Javascript code which can be run on older browsers which supports older version of Javascript and as well as modern browsers.

So, my questions are:-

1. What is the default Javascript version it transpiles the code into?
2. Do we have to manually configure Typescript compiler to convert the code into certain versions of Javascript to be able to run your code into modern as well as older browsers? If yes, how can we achieve this? For example: ES3, ES2015, ES2022
3. Do we need Babel transpiler as well? If we are already using the Typescript compiler which compiles and transpiles your Typescript code into Javascript code to be able to run your code in older as well as modern browsers.

Answer (score -1):

1. The one that's specified in tsconfig.json [target: es5](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target)
2. first question
3. Yes while ts converts syntax, it wouldn't convert underlying api (functions call). E.g. [Array.at](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at) is only available from es6 version. For this typescript will warn you (not in all cases). The api is configured with [lib](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib) property in tsconfig.json